Reaction of aniline with sulfuric acid
I'd like to know why a compound I had, when reacted with concentrated sulfuric acid during an identification test, produced a solid compound that appeared carbonized (the solid was grey). After conducting all the tests, I identified the compound as aniline. Therefore, I'd like to know whether the reaction is similar to the reaction of p-nitroaniline with sulfuric acid or if it is due to the sulfonation of the aromatic ring. I couldn't find any information indicating that a solid is formed during sulfonation. Can you help me?

What were the reactions conditions? This may be useful to you https://www.quora.com/Why-is-aniline-treated-with-the-excess-of-concentrated-sulfuric-acid-in-the-preparation-of-sulfanilic-acid

It should be similar to p-nitroaniline case https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147532/p-nitroaniline-reaction-with-sulfuric-acid

There were no specific conditions; I just added a bit of sulfuric acid to the unknown compound, all at ambient conditions.

Then most likely your product was the anilinium hydrosulfate

See this post: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/reversible-sulfonation-of-aniline and the linked post in the comment.
